# Assigning a 2D array to void*

Tags: c

I am passing a chunk of memory to my subroutine. In the subroutine I am assigning parts of this memory to internal 1D array pointers.

```
typedef struct
{
    // float a[SIZE_A];
    // float b[SIZE_B];
    // float c[SIZE_C1][SIZE_C2];

    float* a;
    float* b;
    float c[][SIZE_C2]; // float** c;
} OBJ;


void init( OBJ* obj, void* mem )
{
    float* mem_p = (float*)mem; 

    obj->a = mem_p; 
    mem_p += SIZE_A;

    obj->b = mem_p; 
    mem_p += SIZE_B;

    obj->c = ? 

}
```

How would I assign a 3rd member which is 2D array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration `float c[][SIZE_C2]` in your struct declares an array of arrays which are stored inline in your struct.  This declaration does not hold any pointers which refer to an array stored elsewhere.

If you wish to keep the struct signature you have currently, you can populate `c` as follows:

```
memcpy(&obj->c, mem_p, SIZE_C1 * SIZE_C2 * sizeof(float));
```

This copies the data from `mem_p` into the contiguous array of arrays `c`, after which `c` does not reference any data from `mem` as is the case with `a` and `b`, but instead holds its own copy of the data.

Keep in mind that your struct currently holds `c` as a "flexible array member", as the outermost array has an unspecified size, which means your struct must be dynamically allocated via `malloc` or similar and must be given extra space to hold the array elements at the end:

```
OBJ *obj = malloc(sizeof *obj + SIZE_C1 * sizeof(float));
```

If you intend in only storing pointers in `obj` which refer to memory referenced by `mem` without storing separate copies, so that `c` is consistent with `a` and `b`, you will have to change the declaration of `c` in your struct to the following:

```
float (*c)[SIZE_C2];
```

This declares `c` to be a "pointer to an array of `SIZE_C2` elements" (which may be in a contiguous sequence of arrays), rather than an "array of arrays of `SIZE_C2` elements".

This can be populated within your `init` function as follows:

```
obj->c = (float (*)[SIZE_C2]) mem_p;
```

If you are looking to assign further `float` fields after `c`, you can continue incrementing `mem_p` like so, without casting it to a pointer-to-array, as the size of an array in C is just the size of its element type multiplied by the number of its elements:

```
/* sizeof(float [SIZE_C2]) == SIZE_C2 * sizeof(float) */
/* mem_p is a `float *` so goes up in steps of `sizeof(float)` */
mem_p += SIZE_C1 * SIZE_C2;
```

With this approach, elements can still be accessed as `obj->c[1][2]`, just as with your current struct's signature.

Since pointers to arrays are slightly tricky to use in C, and require your inner array to have a fixed size, you may find it more appropriate to store `c` as just a regular single `float *` pointer and address elements manually yourself as though it were a 2-dimensional array, e.g.:

```
float f = obj->c[row * SIZE_C2 + col];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this and maybe you overcomplicated the whole thing. As I understand this you started off with statically allocated struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    float a[SIZE_A];
    float b[SIZE_B];
    float c[SIZE_C1][SIZE_C2];
} OBJ;
```

and now you want the memory to be dynamically allocated. So you allocate a chunk of memory of size `sizeof(float) * (SIZE_A + SIZE_B + SIZE_C1 * SIZE_C2)` and set pointers in the struct to that memory.

But notice how that chunk of memory is exactly the size of your original struct? So why not allocate the original struct dynamically instead of changing the members of the struct to pointers?

```
void init( OBJ** obj, void* mem )
{
    *obj = (Obj*)mem;
    memset(mem, 0, sizeof(OBJ));
}

void cleanup( OBJ** obj) {
    free(*obj);
    *obj = NULL;
}
```

You might even move the malloc() into the init() function to make it even easier to use just like I have the free() call in cleanup().

Answer (score -1):

You can't. In your struct `float c[][SIZE_C2];` is a 2 dimensional array of floats that lives inside the struct. It is not a pointer to something that you can point to the memory you allocated. You have to make c a pointer to a 2 dimensional array like this:

```
#define SIZE_A 4
#define SIZE_B 8
#define SIZE_C1 12
#define SIZE_C2 16

struct Float2D {
    float c[0][SIZE_C2];
};

typedef struct
{
    // float a[SIZE_A];
    // float b[SIZE_B];
    // float c[SIZE_C1][SIZE_C2];

    float* a;
    float* b;
    struct Float2D *c;
} OBJ;


void init( OBJ* obj, void* mem )
{
    float* mem_p = (float*)mem; 

    obj->a = mem_p; 
    mem_p += SIZE_A;

    obj->b = mem_p; 
    mem_p += SIZE_B;

    obj->c = (struct Float2D*)mem_p;
}
```

Note: The 0 in `float c[0][SIZE_C2];` is required as you can not have a struct with only a flex array. This could be a gcc compiler extension. Maybe you can figure out how to specify the type without extra struct.

Comment: There is no need to pack the array into a `struct`. Plus your code uses a cast without need. If you don't know how to do it correctly and type-safe please don't answer such questions.

Comment: 1) I already mentioned not using a struct in the answer but the syntax for a pointer to a flexible 2D array is horrible. Using a struct makes it easy to read and understand. 2) Which cast do you mean? The only one I've added is `(struct Float2D*)` and that one is very much needed. 3) If you know it so much better than why don't you write a better answer? So far you only demonstrated that you are wrong.

Comment: There is nothing like a "flexible array".  Only flexibme array **members**. They don't exist outside of a `struct`. The syntax is not "horrible" at all, **if one has understood the language syntax**. Using a `struct` makes it complicated to hande, makes the code less obvious/maintainable while not providing any benefit at all. 2) Casts like that are an indicator of a bad design. Use correct types.. 3) Nice try, but I'm long out of Kindergarten, no need to show off. Everyone knowing the language will understand who's wrong. In case you want to improve:http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Comment: The syntax is horrible. That's an opinion and you aren't going to change mine there. 2) Yes, the cast is an indicator of bad design. But the design is a given in the question. A simple `void *` is passed into the function and then cast to `float *`. The cast I've added to assign the `struct Floadt2D*` is very much needed, just ask your compiler if you can't see that: `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`. Even if you don't use a struct the cast is still very much needed as you can see in the other answer: `obj->c = (float (*)[SIZE_C2]) mem_p;`.

Comment: 2) That't the fundamental problem with the question. Let apart it lacks an [mcve], this code could also invoke undefined behaviour. In fact the code is even more fishy than initially considered. I'd not be surprise the whole think will just blow up with agreesive optimisation on modern compilers like gcc or clang. And repeating what you already wrote does not make your statement more correct. Sidenote: "just aks your compiler" is a terrible advice for C (and C++, too). That#s the general problem with a weakly typed language like C.

Comment: There are many cases where the compiler accepts bad code. But when even the compiler points out problems one can generally trust something is wrong. I've never seen the "assignment from incompatible pointer type" to be wrong. -- What makes you think the code would blow up under optimization? I don't see anything dangerous there. It simply splits up an allocated chunk of memory into 3 regions. Nothing malloc() itself doesn't do million times a day.